# Stay in the same tab after refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

Stay in the same tab after refreshing

after I refresh the page  text1 appear(because its style in css is defined as display:block) but I want the last used tab. how can I do that. this is the jsp code

```
 

<button class="btn special"  id="cl1"  value="Мій профіль" onclick="tabs()" >Мій профіль</button>
    <button class="btn" id="cl2" value="Заявки" onclick="tabs()">Мої запити</button>
<button class="btn" id="cl3" value="Створити запит" onclick="tabs()">Створити запит</button>
    <div class="tabShow"id="firstoption">
один
   </div>
   <div class="tabShow"id="secondoption">
два
   </div>
   <div class="tabShow"id="thirdoption">
три
   </div>
<script>
    function tabs(){
        const btnop1=document.getElementById("cl1");
        const btnop2=document.getElementById("cl2");
        const btnop3=document.getElementById("cl3");
       
        const text1=document.getElementById("firstoption");
        const text2=document.getElementById("secondoption");
        const text3=document.getElementById("thirdoption");
   
        btnop1.onclick=function (){
            text3.style.display="none";
            text2.style.display="none";
            text1.style.display="block";
        
        }
  btnop2.onclick=function (){
            text1.style.display="none";
            text3.style.display="none";
            text2.style.display="block";
          
        }
        btnop3.onclick=function (){

            text1.style.display="none";
            text2.style.display="none";
            text3.style.display="block";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon reloading the tab, the changes you made to the CSS dynamically are gone. If you want persistence, you will need to use something like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the state when pressing a button and load the state when your page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You must use something like the `localstorage` to persist any variable after reloadings

HTML

```
<button class="btn special" id="cl1" value="Мій профіль" onclick="tabs()">
    Мій профіль
  </button>
<button class="btn" id="cl2" value="Заявки" onclick="tabs()">
    Мої запити
  </button>
<button class="btn" id="cl3" value="Створити запит" onclick="tabs()">
    Створити запит
  </button>
<div class="tabShow" id="firstoption">
  один
</div>
<div class="tabShow" id="secondoption">
  два
</div>
<div class="tabShow" id="thirdoption">
  три
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const text1 = document.getElementById('firstoption')
const text2 = document.getElementById('secondoption')
const text3 = document.getElementById('thirdoption')

const textStyles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('textStyles'))
text3.style.display = textStyles.text3
text2.style.display = textStyles.text2
text1.style.display = textStyles.text1

function tabs() {
  const btnop1 = document.getElementById('cl1')
  const btnop2 = document.getElementById('cl2')
  const btnop3 = document.getElementById('cl3')

  btnop1.onclick = function() {
    text3.style.display = 'none'
    text2.style.display = 'none'
    text1.style.display = 'block'
    localStorage.setItem('textStyles', JSON.stringify({
      text3: text3.style.display,
      text2: text2.style.display,
      text1: text1.style.display
    }))
  }
  btnop2.onclick = function() {
    text1.style.display = 'none'
    text3.style.display = 'none'
    text2.style.display = 'block'
    localStorage.setItem('textStyles', JSON.stringify({
      text3: text3.style.display,
      text2: text2.style.display,
      text1: text1.style.display
    }))
  }
  btnop3.onclick = function() {
    text1.style.display = 'none'
    text2.style.display = 'none'
    text3.style.display = 'block'
    localStorage.setItem('textStyles', JSON.stringify({
      text3: text3.style.display,
      text2: text2.style.display,
      text1: text1.style.display
    }))
  }
}
```